# How to train an existing spacy model with my custom training data?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, spacy, spacy-3

I want to train the existing spacy model "en_core_web_sm" with my own custom data. Let's say for example, I created some training data to detect actions. The result I want to achieve is:

```
"Drift on 2022-01-02": DRIFT - ACTION, 2022-01-02 - DATE
"Fight on 2023-02-02": FIGHT - ACTION, 2023-02-02 - DATE
```

But I am getting only my custom entity:

```
"Drift on 2022-01-02": DRIFT - ACTION
"Fight on 2023-02-02": FIGHT - ACTION
```

The "en_core_web_sm" detects the DATE entity easily, but when I train my custom model, it does not. How to train the existing "en_core_web_sm" with my custom training data, so it detects ACTION and DATE entities? This is my base config:

```
# This is an auto-generated partial config. To use it with 'spacy train'
# you can run spacy init fill-config to auto-fill all default settings:
# python -m spacy init fill-config ./base_config.cfg ./config.cfg
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = null
[system]
gpu_allocator = null

[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner"]
batch_size = 1000

[components]

[components.tok2vec]
factory = "tok2vec"

[components.tok2vec.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"

[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v2"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["NORM", "PREFIX", "SUFFIX", "SHAPE"]
rows = [5000, 1000, 2500, 2500]
include_static_vectors = false

[components.tok2vec.model.encode]
@architectures = "spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2"
width = 96
depth = 4
window_size = 1
maxout_pieces = 3

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}

[corpora]

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
```

And here is my training data preparation code:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

TRAIN_DATA = [...]

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") # load other spacy model

db = DocBin() # create a DocBin object

for text, annot in tqdm(TRAIN_DATA): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            print("Skipping entity")
        else:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db.add(doc)

db.to_disk("./train.spacy") # save the docbin object
```

I am creating the config.cfg using this command:

```
python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg
```

I am training the module using this command:

```
python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./train.spacy
```